# ROLLO: ideal codes

Tags: coding-theory

In [ROLLO - Rank-Ouroboros, LAKE & LOCKER](https://pqc-rollo.org/doc/rollo-specification_2020-04-21.pdf), Ideal codes are defined in Definition 2.1.4. Thanks to the Lemma 1, it is proved that every block of ideal matrix is non-singular.

Now, why do they say "hence C can be represented under systematic form"? And in the page 11, I read "indeed, the parity-check matrix under systematic form of C if of the form..."   Why has H this form?

Comment: Are you asking generically why non-singular matrices have systematic forms, or why a block matrix with non-singular blocks has a systematic form?

Comment: @Mark  Why a block matrix with non-singular blocks has a systematic form? Thanks. And why the systematic parity check matrix has that form.

Comment: Can anyone help me?

Comment: @Paul I'm not sure, but the authors may be very happy to explain it if you'd send an email to them.